# Replace rotten bottom plate

Tags: wood, framing, garage, carpentry, water-damage

I have attached garage with room above it. It has three exterior facing wall. The wall sits on 3-4 ft concrete. I am seeing some water coming through one of the wall. On the other side of the wall there is a little area for plantation and I suspect that is where the water is coming from. This wall sits on concrete for about 7-8 foot and then it goes down to the floor of the garage.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDeve.jpg)[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I can see the rotten bottom plate in the interior side of the wall in the garage. My question is what is the best way to replace this rotten plate. Is this something a DIY can do or is it best left to professional?

I am attaching the pictures for reference. The area marked in red lines is the bottom plate I can see from poking through the drywall.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the other side of the wall??

Comment: I included the picture from the other side. Right now it’s covered in snow.

Answer (score 3):

If the bottom plate and studs were installed to finish the garage, only to support the drywall, then replacing the bottom plate would be fairly easy. You'd have to remove the drywall, remove the nails from the studs into the bottom plate and them hammer out the bottom plate. If there's any weight from the top plate, you might need a ceiling screw jack to temporarily support it. If any of the studs are rotting, you'll need to cut out the bad sections and sister in some replacement sections. Be sure to use PT wood. You'll also want to find out where the water's leaking in from the outside and seal that off.